# DB2 big strange issue - database is returned to CIRCULAR mode but archive logs keep coming to old archive location

Tags: logging, db2

my DB2 database (v 9.7) is in Circular mode.

```
Current Logging Type:Circular

(USEREXIT) = OFF
(LOGRETAIN) = OFF
(LOGARCHMETH1) = OFF
(LOGARCHMETH2) = OFF
(LOGPRIMARY) = 10
(LOGSECOND) = 10
Path to log files: /home/ctginst1/ctginst1/NODE0000/SQL00001/SQLOGDIR/
```

I had old archive location `/opt/IBM/archive`
and now my hard disk space is full 100% because I have over 500 logs in that location which I cannot find that is defined somewhere.

What is going on?Why archive logs keep coming to old archive log location?

This is really big problem for us I will be thankful for any help

Comment: Unfortunately you don't provide sufficient details about what you did and in what sequence, so I'll start guessing. Logging changes do not take effect until you deactivate the database and take a full offline backup.

Comment: Hi mustaccio, you mean to run db2 force application all, db2stop, and db2start and it should take affect? Please confirm me I did not do that. I did however do the offline backup recently I will check if logs are still coming after some time

Comment: No, I mean `deactivate database` -- it's a command. You do need to force all connections off. And you need to make an offline backup _after_ you make logging configuration changes, not "recently".

Comment: Please close this question as you have asked it on http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91027/db2-big-strange-problem-database-is-returned-to-circular-mode-but-archive-logs (where it belongs)

Comment: Hi Ian OK I will I just can find the option to close it?